# Is it OK to ask input on implementation of a question?

Tags: discussion

This question touches on [this one](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1196/is-it-good-or-bad-practice-to-update-question-with-the-outcome-of-the-implemen), but I'd like to ask a follow-up question.

A question I asked earlier got some helpful answers, and (parts of) it where actually used. I have some specific usabily issues remaining, which I'd like to discus *in context*.

Is a question in the following format appropriate?

```
screenshot
- Is the meaning of the dates shown here clear?
screenshot
- How can I add visibility to the available values that aren't immediately in the viewport?
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you mean by 'implementation' here. If you are asking for some code, libraries, tools, HTML etc then no, those questions aren't on topic here.

User Experience is technology-agnostic. We are concerned with *what* experience the user should be getting. Once that has been determined then you are into are area of figuring out *how* to deliver that experience, and that falls outside of the scope of this site.

Comment: Often, it's a design vs code thing (design in the sense of how things work, not what they look like). My rule of thumb is that the "how" is OK to explore when it's in the sense of "how should I design this user interface" as opposed to "how should I code this user interface".